# How to get Google Forms "edit response URL" from REST API

Tags: google-api, google-forms, google-api-python-client

Google Forms supports the function `getEditResponseUrl()` in Apps Script but I want to access the same function within the REST API or somehow generate the edit response URL.  It looks like this isn't a supported function in the [REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1beta/forms.responses/get).  Is there another way to get the edit response URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there just isn't any other way than using Apps Scripts.